# How to access the container view from some another container

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, containers

scenario:
I had one main view controller,from that view controller i had placed 3 button and 3 container view. For each button click i had enable appropriate container.Here i had home, about us and contact us,From home i need to go the contact us container view.

How to enable the 'contact us'  container view from home container view controller?

[image]

Welcomes more valuable answers, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do the following:

1) Create a custom class for your container view controller (subclass of UIViewController) and set the class of that *container* view controller in Interface Builder to be your custom subclass.

2) Implement some APIs in your custom container view controller class to manage its children. Maybe something like `- (void)switchToAboutVC` and similar (they should call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`).

3) In your child view controllers (such as about, contact us, etc) you can access the parent view controller and make it switch, so it would look like `[(MyCustomContainerController*)[self parentViewController] switchToAboutVC]`.

PS It's fine to do so within the MVC pattern, just make sure that the right object is managing the VC hierarchy — in this case this is your custom container controller. It's very similar to how you would work with a navigation controller except for the fact that each child view controller already has a property to get it's parent navigation controller without the need to search for it in the view controller hierarchy manually.

Comment: it's working fine.but have some problem.-(void)switchviewcontrollrer
{
 _cont_home.hidden=YES;_cont_aontact_Us.hidden=YES;_cont_aboutUs.hidden=NO;} ,  in this performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: called only at the time of loading this main view controller only,how to pass if suppose a value to contact us view-controller container?.

Comment: yes, In this i want to pass a value from parentviewcontroller to child view controller,so i try the performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:, it only called the one time at the load of the main view controller.so if suppose i want to pass a data from view controller, suppose in this case i am passing from .--(void)switchviewcontrollrer this method to child view controller, ow can i pass a value to that child view controller container?

Comment: How do you expect the data to be passed when using `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`? Are you using `prepareForSegue` method?. It also depends on what kind of data you want to pass. Usually you just set the necessary data by accessing setters on child view controllers. I suspect the reason why `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` doesn't work is because all 3 VCs are already in the hierarchy and you are only manipulating views to hide/show specific view controllers. Better solution would be to remove/add view of those VCs in the view hierarchy.

Comment: How add a container through code ? Have any tutorial link for this type of container view ? please past a link here thank you.

Comment: A container is just a view controller. The tricky part is managing child view controllers. There is a good documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Answer (score 0):

My solution is define functions in the controller to manipulate your container views. in each view, you can always call viewController function with appropriate parameters in order to modify or access to another view.

For example:

In UIViewController:

```
//public function !
-(void)modifyContainer1() {
   //place here code to modify container 1
}

//public function !
-(void)modifyContainer2() {
   //place here code to modify container 1
}
```

and in your container, just call:

```
[self.viewController modifyContainer1];
//etc.
```

or if you want to get back container 1 to call function directly:

```
-(UIContainerView*)getContainer1 {
   //return self.container1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not so good to do so, U R breaking (somehow) the MVC Design Pattern.
U better connect between your container view via `NSNotificationCenter`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:<your_controller>
                                         selector:@selector(method)
                                             name:@"name_of_notification"
                                           object:<any_linear_object_u_want>];
```

Now the sender will post the NSNotificationCenter:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"name_of_notification" object:<any_linear_object_u_want>];
```

Comment: Using notifications for this is somewhat similar to using singletons, so it's arguably even worse. What if you have several containers like that and all of them are listening to the notification?